# Cant remove underline from links

Tags: css

I'm building a website and in the social buttons area I'm having a problem removing the underline with text-decoration:none;

Can you please view [this link](http://juanalvarez.dj/index2.php), then click on the Social button in the upper right. You can see two images and a text link that are underlined. No matter where I put the code, the underlining is there. Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not `text-decoration` that is the problem. Set your `border: 0` in those elements, as you have a `border-bottom` property on each of those anchor tags.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `border-bottom: 1px solid #9FC54E;` from `.panel a`.

Answer (score 3):

it's not an underline.  it's a border on the bottom of `a` tags under `.panel`.

Comment: You're welcome.  Haha.  Thanks for thanking all 3 of us simultaneous answerers.